# How can i use PrintStream.print() replacing of PrintStream.println() in socket programing of java

Tags: java, sockets

I don't want to use println() method. Please give me any alternative of println() method. when i use print() or write() my socket program is not getting request and not sending response. please help me.

Server code is

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
 socket.getInputStream()));
out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true, "UTF-8");
 s = in.readLine();
if (s.equals("")) {
 try {
  socket.close();
  in.close();
  out.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
  }
  }
.
.
.
.
.
.
String b;
if (timeInMin > 0 && timeInMin <= 600000) {
b = "B:1";
 out.println(b); // send data to client
} else {
 b = "B:0";
 out.println(b); // send data to client
}
try {
 } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
}
 }
} catch (IOException e) {
out.println(e);
} finally {
try {
                    socket.close();
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your client is reading the stream using `readLine()` method.

Therefore, it seems to read correctly when the server actually prints a line. When the server simply prints, your client is waiting on the stream to finish the line before retrieving the string it just read.

Try reading differently from the client.